# Vuetify treeview not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to run a vuetify app in a cloud platform. I am allowed to paste html code in.

Problem is that the tree icons don't get rendered properly. I believe the cloud platform runs angular too.

The code I am pasting is this. This runs fine on a standalone page. But when I insert this (without the html, body, head, title, doctype tags) into the platform. It looks like the image below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <v-app>
                <v-content>
                    <v-container fluid>
                        <template>
                            <v-treeview
                              selectable
                              selected-color="red"
                              :items="items"
                            ></v-treeview>
                          </template>
                    </v-container>
                </v-content>
            </v-app>
        </div>
        <script>
            new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                vuetify: new Vuetify({
                    icons : {
                        iconfont : 'md'
                    }
                }),
                data: () => ({
                    items: [
                        {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Applications :',
                        children: [
                            { id: 2, name: 'Calendar : app' },
                            { id: 3, name: 'Chrome : app' },
                            { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm : app' },
                        ],
                        },
                        {
                        id: 5,
                        name: 'Documents :',
                        children: [
                            {
                            id: 6,
                            name: 'vuetify :',
                            children: [
                                {
                                id: 7,
                                name: 'src :',
                                children: [
                                    { id: 8, name: 'index : ts' },
                                    { id: 9, name: 'bootstrap : ts' },
                                ],
                                },
                            ],
                            },
                            {
                            id: 10,
                            name: 'material2 :',
                            children: [
                                {
                                id: 11,
                                name: 'src :',
                                children: [
                                    { id: 12, name: 'v-btn : ts' },
                                    { id: 13, name: 'v-card : ts' },
                                    { id: 14, name: 'v-window : ts' },
                                ],
                                },
                            ],
                            },
                        ],
                        },
                        {
                        id: 15,
                        name: 'Downloads :',
                        children: [
                            { id: 16, name: 'October : pdf' },
                            { id: 17, name: 'November : pdf' },
                            { id: 18, name: 'Tutorial : html' },
                        ],
                        },
                        {
                        id: 19,
                        name: 'Videos :',
                        children: [
                            {
                            id: 20,
                            name: 'Tutorials :',
                            children: [
                                { id: 21, name: 'Basic layouts : mp4' },
                                { id: 22, name: 'Advanced techniques : mp4' },
                                { id: 23, name: 'All about app : dir' },
                            ],
                            },
                            { id: 24, name: 'Intro : mov' },
                            { id: 25, name: 'Conference introduction : avi' },
                        ],
                        },
                    ],
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I compared to where it was working, and the circled parts are different.

[image]